# How to load images of a directories in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

I am starting to learn vue.js and the following problem has been presented to me, I am creating an SFC and when exporting the images inside the folder src / assets / logo.png I do not load the image, this is the code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="row">
      <img :src="imagen" alt="" id="">
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <your-list></your-list>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import YourList from './components/YourList'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    'your-list': YourList
  },
  data() {
    return{
      imagen: './assets/logo.png'
    }
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

The solution I have found is to import the logo in the following way:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="row">
      <img :src="imagen" alt="" id="">
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <your-list></your-list>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import YourList from './components/YourList'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    'your-list': YourList
  },
  data() {
    return{
      imagen: './assets/logo.png'
    }
    }
  }
</script>


<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

I added an import to bring the image and be able to show it, my doubt would be if I have to use 20 images I would have to do it that way, I do not know if it is the most optimal way. I'm using @ vue/cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `require` to make webpack resolve it correctly.

```
data() {
  return {
    imagen: require('./assets/logo.png')
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly, I'm starting with vue and this question had arisen